# Capture multiple words in group

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse something in Python where I have a string, a number, and then an undetermined amount of strings after the number. I would like to be able to put all the remaining strings (in this case "D e") into one group for processing later. This is the code I have:

```
m = re.match(r"(\w+) (\w+) (*)", "de 2166 D e")
```

What should I be doing to create a group of "D e"?

Comment: Example text would help to get an accurate answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is missing `.`. (`.` match any character except newline)

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(\w+) (\w+) (.*)", "de 2166 D e")
    #                           ^
>>> m.groups()
('de', '2166', 'D e')
```

If you want to extract only the 3rd group, use [`MatchObject.group`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group):

```
>>> m.group(3)
'D e'
```

---

**EDIT** suggested by Joe Lewis:

Use following regular expression if you want to accept only digits for the second group. (`\w` -> `\d`)

```
r"(\w+) (\d+) (.*)"
#         ^
```